# Difference Between Partitions and Multiple Outputs in a ParDo?

Tags: python, apache-beam

I'm new to Apache Beam and using the Python SDK. Let's say I have a PCollection with some elements that look like this:

```js
{"item": "foo", "color": "green", "date": "2020-10-30"}
{"item": "bar", "color": "blue", "date": "2020-10-30"}
{"item": "bar", "color": "green", "date": "2020-10-30"}
{"item": "foo", "color": "blue", "date": "2020-10-30"}
```

If I want to split this into several PCollections based on some element attribute, it seems that I have the choice of `Partition` or `ParDo` with tags (and using `with_outputs()` when the `ParDo` is invoked).

Are there guidelines when I would use `Partition` over `ParDo`? It seems like `Partition` is meant for splitting a PCollection where the resulting PCollections all have the same schema ([link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#partition)), whereas a `ParDo` *could* be used to accomplish that, but is better used for splitting a PCollection into multiple PCollections each with a different schema ([link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs)). Am I understanding the documentation correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ParDo** specifies a generic parallel processing and the runner will manage this "fanout", while **Partition** has no intention for a parallel but it is designed for spliting a collection into a sequence of sub-collections with the logic determined by a function which you create.

A typical user case for **partition** can be that of grouping students by percentile and passing groups to their corresponding downstream steps. **Notice** that different group of student can have different downstream process, and this is just not what **ParDo** is designed for.

In addition, another difference between **Partition** and **ParDo** is that the former must have a predefined partition number while the latter has no such concept.

Comment: Ok, I think the idea of Partition is now clear to me—I had missed the concept of the fixed size that has to be supplied at graph construction time.

Comment: Note that Partition is just a special case of ParDo that emits each input, as is, to exactly one output. (In fact, it's just implemented as a ParDo that does exactly that.)